# Как ровно разместить фото с разными размерами

Tags: html, css, html5, веб-программирование

Есть сайт https://www.felixkunze.com/ на основной странице расположены фото(~100), у каждого фото своя высота и ширина и т.е если задавать по одной то фото выглядят плохо.
Смог сделать как на сайте (для 1920х1080 расширения экрана браузера Chrome) с помощью установки высоты для каждой строки вручную. Вопрос, можно ли сделать это по другому и как

Репозиторий: https://github.com/kriillxp/DigitalPortfolioProject

Comment: float: left, colomn-count: 3, что то из этого попробуйте